# Echo chained command into clipboard

Tags: bash, macos

I have a script that parses a response from AWS IAM, creates a file with the environment variables and stores the following command in the user's clipboard, used to source the environment variables into their shell:

relevant line in script:

`echo -e "source $env_file_name" | pbcopy`

results in this being the clipboard contents:

`source NAME_OF_FILE`

This works - when the user runs `` `pbpaste` ``, the environment variables are set, and the user has access to resources. However, if I wanted to perform cleanup of that file by storing a chained command in the clipboard, the second command is never reached:

`echo -e "source $env_file_name;rm $env_file_name" | pbcopy`

I've tried variations such as:

`echo -e "source $env_file_name && rm $env_file_name" | pbcopy`

When pasting:

```sh
~ > `pbpaste`                                                                                                                                                                                          
zsh: command not found: ;rm
```

It is clearly intepreting the `&&` and `` ` `` as string literals, and I am unsure how to get around this.

Comment: I'd be tempted to write the environment variable file so it ends with a command to delete itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only processing normally done after expanding a command substitution is word splitting and filename expansion. If you want the process other shell syntax such as `;` to separate commands, you have to use `eval`.

```
eval "$(pbpaste)"
```